# How i can validate the DOMDocument load function wheather it is working or not

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

Am working with feeds parsing Using Dom Document.

```
$url = 'http://www.blogxxx.com/feed';
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load($url);
```

How to validate wheather my load function loaded the passes url or not,if url is going down it keep processing.

Any solution other then

```
$loadUrl =  $rss->load($url);
if($loadUrl){
}else{
echo 'Url Seems to be down';
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php, “Return value”